# The instrument forever with us

Tags: riddle, word

In life, we always had an instrument with us. Even the poor and the rich have it.

This instrument can be used to show:

- Encouragement
- Direction
- Aggression
- Love
- Promise

This instrument cannot speak. What is this instrument?

Comment: Should have used "provoke" instead of "Aggression". Dammit. A better word to describe but someone already answered it :/.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is

> Your hand. (More specifically, your 5 fingers.)

**Encouragement**

> This is the *thumb*. A "thumbs-up" is often a sign of encouragement.

**Direction**

> The *index finger*. It is used to point the way.

**Aggression**

> The *middle finger*. The famous "[one-finger salute](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/one-finger_salute)" is a definite sign of aggression.

**Love**

> The *ring finger* is where we place a wedding ring, a symbol of undying love.

**Promise**

> The *pinky finger*. It is used for "[pinky promises](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinky_swear)".

Comment: Aww you beat me to it. Game was already loading, and then it started so I couldn't type the answer lol

Comment: Perfect answer. Never heard that middle finger was also known as the "one hand salute". I was only known that people use middle finger just to show that he/she is extremely angry with a person, naturally a way to say, "f*ck you".

Comment: Could have used "provoke" as a better way to represent the 3rd finger

Answer (score 3):

> The hands.

Some people do not have it, but it in general it is possessed by rich and poor alike.

Encouragement:

> Thumbs up

Direction:

> Pointing

Aggression:

> Middle finger, fist grip

Love:

> Caressing, [love hand sign](http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/woman-hand-making-sign-heart-25753409.jpg)

Promise:

> Pinkie promise

This instrument cannot speak:

> No it can't, and body language isn't speaking